# line 14: [: 55.5: integer expression expected --shell error

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sh

I'm getting error for line 8,11,14,17 .
the program is

```
#!/bin/sh

read a      
b=$(grep -i $a TeamScore.txt| awk 'BEGIN{FS =" "}{print ($2+$4)/2}')
echo "the avg is $b"
if [ "$b" -ge 80]                             #line8
then
echo "1st class "
elif [ "$b" -lt 80 ] || [ "$b" -ge 70 ]       #line11
then
echo "2nd class"
elif [ "$b" -lt 70 ] || [ "$b" -ge 60 ]       #line14
then
echo "3rd class"
elif [ "$b" -lt 60 ]                          #line17
then
echo "fail"
else
echo "code not working"
fi
```

I'm new to unix and shell scripting and i would like to whats wrong and how can i fix it.the TeamScore.txt contains a table of names and their score(for 2 exams).

Comment: Copy paste your script to http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors as they are seen.

Comment: @aicastell The `test` command doesn't see the quotes, those are processed by the shell. It shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Remember, all CLI arguments are strings. It's up to the application to interpret them as numbers if it wants.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `test` command only understands integers, but you're setting `b` to `55.5`, which contains a fraction. Change the `awk` command to round it down.

```
b=$(grep -i $a TeamScore.txt| awk 'BEGIN{FS =" "}{print int(($2+$4)/2)}')
```

You also need a space before `]` on line #8.

Answer (score 1):

Line 8: add an extra space:

```
if [ "$b" -ge 80 SPACE_HERE_REQUIRED ]
```

Line11, line14 and line17: number operators can't be compared with strings, so use $b instead of "$b", so, for example, use this

```
if [ $b -ge 80 ]
```

instead of:

```
if [ "$b" -ge 80 ]
```